# Зачем нужен appmodul.cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Долго искал начало одной программы. Долго, пока не пришла в голу мысль о пошаговом обходе.

Все бы хорошо, но вот только точка входа моей программы оказалась в этом файле,стандартной библиотеке C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET\Vc7\atlmfc\src\mfc\appmodul.cpp

Что это за файл, и почему с него начинается выполнение программы?
В линках он не прописан...там вообще ничего не прописано

Comment: Двигайтесь дальше, пока не выйдете из MFC. Любой фреймворк начинается из своих недр, Вы не знали?

Comment: неа) я второкурсник)

Comment: >я второкурсник

тогда незачет :)

Comment: хахаха)
надеюсь мы это потом будем проходить,сейчас этого нет(

спасибо, что подсказали!

Comment: @mega, посоветуете,пожалуйста, литературу, где про это можно почитать(учебник)?

Comment: Я не специализируюсь на `MFC`. Вобщем-то, это логически вытекает из любого учебника по ["основам программирования в `Windows`"](http://google.com/search?q=основы+программирования+в+windows), например.